# Printing Forms Based Off the Status of a Field

Tags: ms-access

In ms-Access I have a form that is used to show defect data with a picture for reporting purposes. this form has a page for every defect occurrence, but not all defects have pictures. I only want to print pages that have the picture populated into that field.

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask], then improve your question (edit). Usually printing should be done by a report (forms display data to work on).

Comment: Reports are best for printing. Open report filtered to records that have picture.